# Logging JConsole output into a CSV file. What logic ist behind the time value?

Tags: java, excel, csv, logging, jconsole

When I open a JConsole window, I am able to save the memory data by rightclicking onto the graph and choose save data as (.csv).

After that the data output is like

> Time,Used,Committed,Max 
>   43738.560828,877853920,4294947296,15032385536

How can I parse the Time into some more comfortable data?

My first idea was trying to parse the data with excel into some readable value, but this was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel removed the decimal separator when you imported the csv. At import time you have to be sure Excel is considering the point (.) as the decimal sepator and not the one of your region.
Once you do that you can format the cell to date and the result will be

> 30/09/2019  13:27:36

Hope I helped

Comment: Thats the solution. Thanks! When I am replacing the "." with a "," and choose some Dates it works best!